# Is it secure to keep Guest account enabled in Windows 8.1 or 10?

Tags: windows-8.1, security, windows-10

I enabled guest account on Windows 8.1, because I wanted to create a network share with access for everyone without a password.

The question is:

Is this secure? Does enabling the guest account allow anonymous users to do other things in addition to accessing the mentioned network share?

I didn't change any other settings or policies, so I'm running with default settings a fresh Windows installation comes with.

I am using Windows 8.1 now, but the question is about Windows 10 too.

Comment: People using the guest account can't install software or hardware, change settings, or create a password.

Comment: You might also want to read [Best Practices for Creating a Secure Guest Account](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/119277-best-practices-creating-secure-guest-account.html) and [How do I create a secure Guest Account in Windows 7?](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-do-i-create-a-secure-guest-account-in-windows-7/)